# Need solution for ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ado.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am asked to make a stored procedure in Oracle for the below query which would take input parameter as `@FID` in there where clause to give me the result.

It consists of 4 columns and the result normally is 100+rows for each of the different inputs.
The initial query is below-

```
SELECT 
    TJV.FID, TD.F_CLASS_NAME,  
    CASE 
       WHEN TJV.job_operation_id = 1 THEN 'INSERT' 
       WHEN TJV.JOB_OPERATION_ID = 2 THEN 'UPDATE' 
       WHEN TJV.job_operation_id = 3 THEN 'DELETE' 
    END AS JOB_OPERATION_TYPE, 
    TJV.OPERATION_DATE 
FROM 
    TB_JOB_VERSION TJV, 
    TB_DICTIONARY TD, TB_UFID TU 
WHERE 
    TJV.JOB_ID = @FID 
    AND TU.FID = TJV.FID 
    AND TU.F_CLASS_ID = TD.F_CLASS_ID;
```

I have then made a procedure like this below but it has thrown the below error message -

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
>   ORA-06512: at TCGM3D.JOB_EXPLORER, line 8 ORA-06512: at line 6

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE job_explorer (
    j_fid IN INT
) AS
    v_fid                  NUMBER;
    v_f_class_name         VARCHAR2(30);
    v_job_operation_type   VARCHAR(100);
    v_operation_date       DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        tjv.fid,
        td.f_class_name,
        CASE
            WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 1 THEN
                'INSERT'
            WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 2 THEN
                'UPDATE'
            WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 3 THEN
                'DELETE'
        END AS job_operation_type,
        tjv.operation_date
    INTO
        v_fid,
        v_f_class_name,
        v_job_operation_type,
        v_operation_date
    FROM
        tcgm3d.tb_job_version   tjv,
        tcgm3d.tb_dictionary    td,
        tcgm3d.tb_ufid          tu
    WHERE
        tjv.job_id = j_fid
        AND tu.fid = tjv.fid
        AND tu.f_class_id = td.f_class_id;

    dbms_output.put_line('FID'
                         || v_fid
                         || 'F_CLASS_NAME'
                         || v_f_class_name
                         || 'JOB_OPERATION_TYPE'
                         || v_job_operation_type
                         || 'OPERATION_DATE'
                         || v_operation_date);

END job_explorer;
```

I have again tried modifying the query using a loop but the results are not tabular and it just comes out like this in the query output window-

```
"FID85225493
F_CLASS_NAMESCE_EL_TRN_POLE_TBL
JOB_OPERATION_TYPEUPDATE
OPERATION_DATE04-JAN-17
FID251101047
F_CLASS_NAMESCE_EL_SEG_SECTION
JOB_OPERATION_TYPEINSERT
OPERATION_DATE04-JAN-17
FID251101038
F_CLASS_NAMEEL_CONNECTOR
JOB_OPERATION_TYPEINSERT
OPERATION_DATE04-JAN-17
FID251100923
F_CLASS_NAMEEL_PAD
JOB_OPERATION_TYPEINSERT
OPERATION_DATE04-JAN-17"
```

My final query for this is below-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE job_explorer (
    j_fid IN INT
) AS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT
            tjv.fid,
            td.f_class_name,
            CASE
                WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 1 THEN
                    'INSERT'
                WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 2 THEN
                    'UPDATE'
                WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 3 THEN
                    'DELETE'
            END AS job_operation_type,
            tjv.operation_date
        FROM
            tcgm3d.tb_job_version   tjv,
            tcgm3d.tb_dictionary    td,
            tcgm3d.tb_ufid          tu
        WHERE
            tjv.job_id = j_fid
            AND tu.fid = tjv.fid
            AND tu.f_class_id = td.f_class_id
    ) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('FID' || rec.fid);
        dbms_output.put_line('F_CLASS_NAME' || rec.f_class_name);
        dbms_output.put_line('JOB_OPERATION_TYPE' || rec.job_operation_type);
        dbms_output.put_line('OPERATION_DATE' || rec.operation_date);
    END LOOP;
END job_explorer;
```

It would help if anyone could help me out in getting the data in tabular format for each row which i then has to query in a datatable in ado.net.

Comment: just change dbms_output.put_line to one call and concatenate all the fields.

Comment: See also the Microsoft docs on how to fill a dataset using Oracle ref cursors. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ref-cursor-examples

Comment: The data in the cursor (rec) is tabular, the [dbms_output](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999434) that is not. Each call to dbms_output.put_line produces 1 line of output. You can concatenate each field (with suitable delimiters between the fields) or change dbms_output.put_line  to dbms_output.put  (with suitable delimiters between then) then add dbms_output.new_line.

Comment: @Belayer -- my main problem is I need to use this stored procedure to get the data by ado dot net dataset/data table which I want to again bind to a grid view but with this the datatable is just null

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

With this you get answers in tabular form with pipes as delimiter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE job_explorer(j_fid IN INT)
AS
BEGIN
  /* header */
  dbms_output.put_line(       rpad('FID',12)
                       ||'|'||rpad('F_CLASS_NAME',30)
                       ||'|'||rpad('JOB_OPERATION_TYPE',18)
                       ||'|'||rpad('OPERATION_DATE',19)
                       );
  --
  /*data*/
  FOR rec IN (SELECT tjv.fid,
                     td.f_class_name,
                     CASE
                         WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 1 THEN
                             'INSERT'
                         WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 2 THEN
                             'UPDATE'
                         WHEN tjv.job_operation_id = 3 THEN
                             'DELETE'
                     END AS job_operation_type,
                     tjv.operation_date
              FROM tcgm3d.tb_job_version   tjv,
                   tcgm3d.tb_dictionary    td,
                   tcgm3d.tb_ufid          tu
              WHERE tjv.job_id = j_fid
               AND tu.fid = tjv.fid
               AND tu.f_class_id = td.f_class_id
              ) LOOP
       --
      dbms_output.put_line(       lpad(rec.fid,12)
                           ||'|'||rpad(rec.f_class_name,30)
                           ||'|'||rpad(rec.job_operation_type,18)
                           ||'|'||to_char(rec.operation_date,'dd-MON-yy')
                          );
  END LOOP;
END job_explorer;
```

And output will be:

```
FID      |F_CLASS_NAME                  |JOB_OPERATION_TYPE|OPERATION_DATE
 85225493|SCE_EL_TRN_POLE_TBL           |UPDATE            |04-JAN-17
251101047|SCE_EL_SEG_SECTION            |INSERT            |04-JAN-17
251101038|EL_CONNECTOR                  |INSERT            |04-JAN-17
251100923|EL_PAD                        |INSERT            |04-JAN-17
```

Comment: my main problem is I need to use this stored procedure to get the data by ado dot net dataset/data table which I want to again bind to a grid view but with this the datatable is just null

Comment: You can use an output parameter to get this output